# Run time error 91, code was working before now it isn't?

Tags: vba, outlook

My code is supposed to check my inbox for unopened emails that contain csv files. When it encounters one it is supposed to download it with a new name and mark the email as read in a new folder.

Everything was working yesterday and now I am getting a run-time error 91.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim myOlapp         As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace     As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder        As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem          As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachment    As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim avDate()        As String
    Dim vDate           As String
    Dim Address         As String
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim csvCount        As Long
    Dim myDestFolder    As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Const myPath As String = "C:\Saved CSV\"
    ReDim Preserve avDate(3)

    Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    i = 0
    j = 0


    Set myDestFolder = myFolder.Parent.Folders("CSV Emails")

    For i = myFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeName(myFolder.Items(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            Set myItem = myFolder.Items(i)
        End If
        csvCount = 0

        If myItem.UnRead = True Then                                    'Run time error Here'
            avDate = Split(CStr(myItem.ReceivedTime), "/")
            vDate = Mid(avDate(2), 1, 4) & "-" & avDate(1) & "-" & avDate(0)


            If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
                    If LCase(Right(myAttachment.FileName, 3)) = "csv" Then
                        j = j + 1
                        csvCount = csvCount + 1

                        Dim recipientsItem As Object
                        Dim OldMessage As Outlook.MailItem
                        Set OldMessage = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

                        For Each recipientsItem In OldMessage.Recipients
                            If OldMessage.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
                                Address = OldMessage.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                            End If
                            If OldMessage.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
                                Address = mymessage.SenderEmailAddress
                            End If
                        Next recipientsItem

                        myAttachment.SaveAsFile ((myPath) & "," & Address & "," & vDate & " - " & j & " - " & myAttachment.FileName)
                    End If
                Next myAttachment

                If csvCount > 0 Then
                    myItem.UnRead = False
                    myItem.Move myDestFolder
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

SaveAttachments_exit:
  Set myAttachment = Nothing
  Set myItem = Nothing
  Set myNameSpace = Nothing
  Set OldMessage = Nothing
  Exit Sub

SaveAttachments_err:
  MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
    & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
    & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
    & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Error!"
  Resume SaveAttachments_exit


End Sub
```

I am getting an error on

```
If myItem.UnRead = True Then
```

Didn't have the error yesterday. Any help would be appreciated.

I am assuming that it is because the set statement for myItem is within the for loop and it isn't being set properly.

For anyone wondering why I am putting commas in the file name it is so I can extract the senders email address with a -split statement in powershell.

Comment: Your assumption is likely correct.  If the first time through the loop the item is not a MailItem then myItem will be Nothing and you will have issues.  You need to guard against this situation.

Comment: What are your suggestions for doing this?

Comment: Before `If myItem.UnRead = True Then` add a line `If Not myItem Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspect is that this line `Set myItem = myFolder.Items(i)` is never executed, and this will cause your `If` instruction to fail accessing the object property.

This can be caused by several reason:

- **Outlook** doesn't return any mail (`Items.Count = 0`)
- Your `If` condition is never satisfied (`TypeName(myFolder.Items(i))` is never `"MailItem"`)
- Your **default mailbox** is changed, and doesn't contain any `MailBox` Item.
- Technical problems (i.e Can't instantiate an instance of Outlook, Different version of Office, etc.)

---

### Finding the error

To test which of this problem can be, I suggest you to run the code in **debug mode** and executing each instruction **step-by-step** (you can do it by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>).

While still executing the code, check the value of your variables (using your **Local Variable** Window).

This can help you better understanding what's going on with your code, and can be a great help in finding where is the issue.

---

### Check if the object is Not Null

In any case, it's a good practice to check if the object is initialized, before trying accessing it.

To do that, you can add this instruction:

```
If Not myItem Is Nothing then
    If myItem.UnRead = True Then
        'rest of your code...
```

---

Hope this helps.